# need java objective type questions in pdf format

Tags: java

I want to practice java programs ..can anyone point me a web site which contains java objective type questions in pdf format and readiliy available to download?

Comment: could you elaborate on what you mean by 'objective type'?

Comment: questions and answers (some options given for that)

Comment: By questions and answers, do you mean SCJP-style questions or exercises?

Comment: any style not only SCJP ..but SCJP is also fine ..

Comment: I added a link in the answers. Have fun ;)

Comment: This is a subjective question, please edit and mark Community Wiki.

Comment: you can ask programming questions here, do not ask for your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.akgupta.com/Java/mock_exam.htm

Answer (score 2):

Sidharth, if you're looking for mock exams in the same style as SCJP, the following is a good site to stop by. It's not in PDF format but there's nothing stopping you from printing to PDF once you've finished an exam.

[JavaBlackBelt](http://solutions.javablackbelt.com/m/community-edition-exams.html)

Answer (score 1):

Sidharth, I think this website also provides you the objective type, But not in Pdf format.
http://www.javaranch.com/roundup.jsp